# Installing Synedit on Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, synedit, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to install the latest Unicode version of `TSynEdit` in the Delphi 10 Seattle IDE. It builds OK but when installing I get the error:

> Access violation at address 27158679 in module 'bds.exe'. Read
>   of address 00000010

It installs OK on previous versions up to XE8.

I tried putting showmessages() at the start of the register procedure but AV error still occurs before the registration.

Has anyone found a work around for this ?

Comment: Does the repo history suggest that the code has been adapted to support Seattle?

Comment: I just tried it via GetIt on D10Seattle. Installs fine on my machine.

Comment: I think in general, GetIt is the quick and easy way to solve any such problem. However, if you want more control over third party dependencies, for instance you wish to include the source code in your project, then you need to do a bit more than just use GetIt.

Comment: @LU RD Getit list Synedit TurboPack, is this the complete synedit edit control ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes.

Comment: @LU RD - I just tried it and it works, I obviously have not got the latest version as I thought. Thanks for that !  BTW, I had never even looked at Getit before, so I learned something new today...cheers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GetIt Package Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/GetIt_Package_Manager) contains the latest version of `TSynEdit`.

You can reach `GetIt` from the tools menu in the IDE.
It downloads/compiles/installs without errors on my D10Seattle machine.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, SourceForge files are pretty old. But you can download SynEdit components from [github](https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit/archive/master.zip). It has project files for newer Delphi versions. I just built and installed it for 10.2 Tokyo.